# XML output not displayed in browser

Tags: php, simplexml

I am using a 'MYJADU' API,  to get XML data and then parse the data for display, however, for some reason the data is not being displayed in the browser. I am not sure what I am missing. Below is the code I have so far. Thank you.

```
    <?p

    $path = 'http://{domain}/api/documents/all.xml?api_key={api_key}';

     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; 
     Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Jadu');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

      $response = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);

     $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response); 
     foreach ($xml->document as $document) { 
     $documentTitle = (string) $document->title;
     echo htmlentities($documentTitle, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ‘<br>'
      }

     ?>
```

Comment: what do you have in $response from curl?

Comment: The $response variable should return a list of all documents within a Jadu CMS instance in a structured XML response but i am not sure if that is actually being returned. I used the used the postman app on chrome to see the response from the api link and the api did return an XML response.